# to omitted in passive structure

Tags: passive-voice

kindly check the sentence.''.....but tells Eddard about the Walkers first and asks that word be sent back to his mother.''

why there is no 'to' before "be sent"?

I take it as a passive sentence. can I omit 'to' here?  Will that be acceptable grammatically?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest that you go through the _subjunctive mood_ once.

Comment: Thank you. I will.

Comment: Understood. those who are not native sometimes find it difficult to recognize which part of grammar is used for a given topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only *can* you omit "to" here, you *must*—it would be incorrect to insert "to" here.

The word "be" here is being used in the [subjunctive mood](https://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Orange%20Level/O23_Subjunctive_Mood.html), hence the unusual "that word be" construction.  A valid (non-subjunctive) sentence using "to be sent" would be "...asks *for* word *to be* sent..."

Comment: Understood. those who are not native sometimes find it difficult to recognize which part of grammar is used for a given topic. Thank you.

Comment: The verb 'send' is in the passive voice, indeed!